I am building an application with a Open-AI API but i don't get the desired output
I am building an application with integrated Open-AI API but I don't get the desired output. The idea is that i use pre-prompt that get's send with the request.

User submits a story on a pre defined chapter.
The API should ask 5 questions relevant to the user input to gather more information on the submitted story.
The API uses the information to generate an AI enhanced story relevant to user input.

Example of the problem (generated question labels):
enter image description here
AI-Vragen:
2.
4. a. Hoe heeft de aanwezigheid van zowel biologische als stiefouders je leven beïnvloed?
5. b. Kun je een specifieke herinnering delen die je koestert met een van deze familieleden?
6. c. Op welke manieren hebben jullie als gezin samen gebouwd aan jullie gedeelde geschiedenis en tradities?
As you can see, I get a list with the wrong numbering. The API should ask 5 questions relevant to the user input. Instead I get a weirdly numbered list and unwanted labels (a., b., c.). Is there anybody who understands the problem and can help me find a solution?
I tried searching the web for a solution as well as using all my available prompts with chat-GPT 01-preview and am now trying to find a solution using chat-GPT 4o. I am already trying to find a solution for the last 11 hours..
